# How do I turn a git clone into a fork and then push to heroku from the fork?

Tags: git, heroku, github, fork, clone

I cloned a repository thinking I wouldn't need to change anything. Now I want to change something.

I forked the code on github but now I'm unsure what to do next. I don't want to make the changes and then then accidentally commit to the repo I cloned from.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your local `git` repository determines where to push / pull based on "remotes". Right now, your local repository two remotes, `origin` (which right now points to the Github repository you cloned) and `heroku` (which points to a Heroku repository).

You forked the origin to a new repository on Github; let's say the the old one was `https://github.com/bob/website.git` and your fork is `https://github.com/pixelfairy/website.git`.

If you do

```
git remote -v
```

You should see something like

```
origin  https://github.com/bob/website.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/bob/website.git (push)
...
```

We can change this so that `origin` points to your fork. Do

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/pixelfairy/website.git
```

Now `git remote -v` should output

```
origin  https://github.com/pixelfairy/website.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/pixelfairy/website.git (push)
...
```

You can now `push` and `pull` as you did before, and it will use your fork instead of the originally cloned repository.

Comment: Trying this now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @tbekolay answer, if needed, you can still fetch / pull from the original branch that was cloned in order to keep up with changes from there.  Do this by adding an "upstream" ( or other named ) remote that still points to the original remote ( bob in this case ).

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/bob/website.git
```

Then you can update your code by pulling from there from time to time:

```
git pull upstream <branch name>
```

If you ever want to change the new remote use:

```
git remote set-url upstream <new url>
```

Comment: to easily see all of your remote settings use:
git remote -v